# R: column sum in a data.table without for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, data.table

I have a data.table of the following structure:

```
DT = data.table(ID = rep(c("A", "B"), each=5), 
                DY = 1:5, 
                S = c(0, 50, 50, 200, 50, 5, 20, 5, 20, 25))
```

This `data.table` shall be added by a column `C`, whose entries are just the sum from DY i in 1:5 grouped by ID.
The result for the example above is

```
DT[, C:=c(0, 50, 100, 300, 350, 5, 25, 30, 50, 75)]
```

As I have described, a for-loop is the 1st choice to get the result that I want. But, is there a better way calculating C without a for-loop, especially using the power of the data.table-package?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the result showed, you may need `cumsum` of "S" column grouped by "ID"

```
 DT[, C:=cumsum(S), by = ID]
```

If you need to transform back, as @eddi suggested

```
 DT[, S:=c(C[1L],diff(C)), by = ID]
```

Comment: Quite an elegant way. Is there also quite an elegant back way, so if you have column C and you want to calculate column S?

Comment: I have to study the syntax and the functions diff to understand your answer.